# gstreamer rtsp streaming chain with LGPL elements

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer

The following chain seem to work well to stream video:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=/home/manusha/Downloads/movies/<movie file>.mkv ! decodebin ! ffenc_mpeg4 bitrate=5000000 ! rtpmp4vpay mtu=1400 pt=96 ssrc=0 timestamp-offset=0 seqnum-offset=0 send-config=true ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

This chain is able to receive the stream and play it:

```
gst-launch udpsrc uri=udp://127.0.0.1:5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)MP4V-ES, profile-level-id=(string)1, config=(string)000001b001000001b58913000001000000012000c48d88007d0a041e1463000001b24c61766335322e3132332e30, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)298758266, clock-base=(uint)3097828288, seqnum-base=(uint)63478" ! rtpmp4vdepay ! ffdec_mpeg4 ! autovideosink
```

My problem is, both ffdec_mpeg4 and ffenc_mpeg4 are GPL licensed and will not suit my purpose because I need to redistribute them. I am lookiing for advice on alternative stream chains that I can form only with LGPL licensed elements. The streaming to be used only inside a LAN, but it need to support HD quality streaming.

Answer (score 1):

ffdec_mpeg4 and ffenc_mpeg4 are not strictly GPL, they are part of GStreamer's FFmpeg plugin set (or Libav), and are container in the LGPL subset. You'll need to recompile gst-libav/gst-ffmpeg with only LGPL plugins (don't use configure --enable-gpl, which your build probably did use), and you'll get the same plugins under LGPL license (see GST_LIBAV_ENABLE_GPL in config.h).

Comment: Great thanks. Looks like it is going to be easier than I though. Will do that.

Answer (score 0):

you have to rebuild it by using following command

```
    sudo ./configure --enable-lgpl '--prefix=/usr'
    make 
    sudo make install
```